# Pen Testing Webapp/Database - Solution

Tags: security, software-testing

I am looking for a system for managing penetration test findings. Wondering if there's a vendor application out there - whereby my penetration testers can "log a finding" - and than manage the workflow around that finding e.g. Open -> Analaysis, -> Pending fix, Fixed - Pending Retest - Closed.

I've looked at Jira / ServiceNow also has an offering - ServiceNow doesn't seem fully baked and the customization. Wondering what others are using to track and manage their penetration test findings.